# How do google drive and dropbox work?

Tags: dropbox, google-drive-api

What do Google drive and drop-box use to synchronize files? Are they based on anything like `ajax/jquery`? I am just a newbie, but I would like to know a bit more about sync. Any help/link?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554680/how-dropbox-works

Answer (score 1):

AJAX and jQuery are javascript, javascript runs only in the browser. Google Drive and Dropbox are written in client side code. As far as I can work out, both clients are written in Visual C++.

This is a very advanced topic to be jumping into, I'd recommend reading some books on basic programming before you go anywhere near this kind of stuff.